# ASP.Net MVC jQuery and plugins loaded in wrong order

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP.Net MVC and attempting to use the TinyMCE HTML editor.

I added this from NuGet - however, it adds an EditorTemplate (`Shared -> EditorTemplates -> tinymce_jquery_full.cshtml`), which then renders the JQuery for TinyMCE within the page - ie. before jQuery scripts are loaded (by default in the MVC templates, at the bottom of the page) - so TinyMCE does not work.

The template is:

```
@*
Don't forget to reference the JQuery Library here, inside your view or layout.
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-x.x.x.min.js")" type="text/javascript">        </script>
*@

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/jquery.tinymce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

(function(){ 

  $(function() { 

      $('#@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(string.Empty)').tinymce({

        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")',
        theme: "advanced",

        height: "500",
        width: "790",
        verify_html : false,
        plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak,restoredraft,codehighlighting,netadvimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : false,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/css/content.css")",
        convert_urls : false,

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js"

    });

  });

})();

</script>

@Html.TextArea(string.Empty, /* Name suffix */
ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue /* Initial value */
)
```

Is there any way of forcing the TinyMCE jQuery code to populate at the bottom of the page, after jQuery scripts have loaded?

Thank you,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the nuget package called?

I tried reproducing this but couldn't find a Tiny MCE package that installs an shared EditorTemplate that you mentioned.